# Avoiding a big image push other layouts out of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I've tried for hours but nothing achieved.

Thats my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
   
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="A dog"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textSize="50sp"></TextView>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/dog"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
   
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in the following screen everything is ok in small and big screens

[image: Title in the top]

But what I really need is to put the text below the image. Changing their order in the container the result is:

[image: Tittle in the bottom]

It works nice for screens taller than the image but for small screens the text is not visible. How can I solve that issue? Please for the solution consider those points:

- The layout that contains the image and text must be centered in his parent (for that example the base layout) (especially for long screens)
- The drawable should keep its original size if screen is big enought, and reduced (keeping the aspect ratio) when the screen is smaller

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested that code and it have the behaviour you are looking for. Let me know if you need more help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ></LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_above="@id/linear2"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ></TextView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageiffel"
                android:src="@drawable/my_image"
                android:layout_above="@id/textView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ></ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should be able to skip all of the LinearLayouts here. Only the RelativeLayout is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You could scale the image to fit a certain width and height

Refer here [Scale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

EDIT:

You could try something like

```
public static final ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE
```

Since: API Level

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax:

```
android:scaleType="centerInside
```

EDIT: Also you may be able to use Bitmap..

Something like..

```
         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        int newWidth = 640;
        int newHeight = 480;

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // create the new Bitmap object
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width,
                height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

        linearLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        setContentView(linearLayout);       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Setting the scaleType of the image to centerInside the layout is the same that the second part of the second image (text is still missing)

Comment: Are these images stored inside of the app, or downloaded from a website or server? If they are stored in the app, why not make the image smaller for HDPI so that way the title will fit in..make different sized image depending on the screen resolution(this is if you have the images stored inside the app).

Comment: I'm testing with resources stored in the app but the background of this question is for using bitmaps recovered from Internet urls

Comment: BTW, You may want to run this and the retrieval of your images in a AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks for your time. This seems to be a valid solution. I'll try to find if is possible to make it within the XML else I'll use your solution. Using a RelativeLayout is posible to avoid the text dissapear (setting the text aligned to the parent's bottom, and below the image) but using that option it is no longer centered in the big screen. There is a way of centering it? Thanks

Comment: No problem. You could always use a ScrollView Layout ;-) .

Comment: Just allow the user to scroll ;-) This may save you some time if possible.